# VBSscript error - Create shortcut to FTP with username and passowrd

Tags: windows, vbscript, ftp, passwords

I have a vbsscript that I can deploy to users that will create a shortcut to an FTP drive on the user's desktop. This script works in this form:

```
Set objShell=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
strDesktopFolder=objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
Set objShortcut=objShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktopFolder & "FTP.lnk")
objShortCut.TargetPath = "ftp://ftp.website.com"
objShortCut.Description = "FTP"
objShortCut.Save
```

This is great, but it requires that the user type a username and password to access the folder. I really need to save the username and password before as part of the deployment and eliminate extra steps for the end-user. Therefore, I want to save the username and password as part of the vbs script when I deploy it. I have come close and can save a username and password with the following:

```
Set objShell=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
strDesktopFolder=objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
Set objShortcut=objShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktopFolder & "FTP.lnk")
objShortCut.TargetPath = "ftp://user:pass@ftp.website.com"
objShortCut.Description = "FTP"
objShortCut.Save
```

However, the issue is that I can't save them correctly. The username format is:

```
user@website.com
```

This is the format for my ftp site. I cannot change that. This format returns an error (800A0005). I need my script to work without error like this:

```
Set objShell=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
strDesktopFolder=objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
Set objShortcut=objShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktopFolder & "FTP.lnk")
objShortCut.TargetPath = "ftp://user@website.com:pass@ftp.website.com"
objShortCut.Description = "FTP"
objShortCut.Save
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your username contains the **@** symbol, and your web browser or the windows explorer does not like it, you must substitute it with the **+** symbol like this :

> user@website.com = user+website.com

```
Set objShell=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
strDesktopFolder=objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
Set objShortcut=objShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktopFolder & "FTP.lnk")
objShortCut.TargetPath = "ftp://user+website.com:pass@ftp.website.com"
objShortCut.Description = "FTP"
objShortCut.Save
```

Comment: Thanks, that resolved it. I figured it was something simple, but I am fairly new to scripting.

Comment: @hackoo What to do in the case of IP